# Difference between BCP versions. On example of exporting data

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am facing the problem with BCP (bulk-copy program) on MSSQL-Server 13.0.
Here it goes:

I am trying to export data with that program but file is always corrupted. I am exporting a .zip file. 
But it works perfect on MSSQL-Server 11.0 - the same command can export any zip file that I need to export.

Command that I am using to export:

```
bcp "select query" queryout "C:\export\myzip.zip" -T -S SERVER_NAME
```

Tried to use -V flag, but it didnt work.

---

Edit 1: After command is used BCP shows me questions about prefix, format and etc - I am using: I 0 0 (space) n

---

Edit 2: The starting bytes of the exported file are: `37 7a bc af 27 1c`

Comment: `but file is always corrupted` are you getting any error

Comment: I dont get any errors while exporting my data.
But when I am trying to open exported data it shows me:
Windows cannot open the folder.
The compressed (zipped) Folder "C:\export\myzip.zip" is invalid

Comment: You should be using a format file which specifies 0 as prefix length. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40860039/243373).

Comment: I am using it.
Edited main question.

Comment: What are the first few bytes of the exported file?

Comment: @vovka15, you need to specify the `-c` BCP argument to create a text file without prompting for file format specifications. That will create a tab-delimited file with cr-lf record terminators.  Simply specifying ".zip" as the file extension will not automatically compress the file; you'll need to compress separately.

Comment: 37 7a bc af 27 1c 00 03

Comment: @DanGuzman How it should help?
I cannot understand.
If I won't specify file format when I am trying to extract it will be created las a dump file.
If I compress that file it will be .zip with that dumpfile into.

Comment: @vovka15, no format file is required with `-c`. That will create a text file with the file format I described that can be read using any text editor.

Comment: @DanGuzman, sorry, still cannot get it. I have .zip file with many files into it. If I create text file what will be next step to get my zip. You said that it can be read using any text editor. But for what?

Comment: BCP does not create compressed files directly.  You'll need to first create the text files with BCP and then compress all those text files into a single compressed zip file. The latter can be done in Powershell.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca.

Comment: Looking [here](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=377ABCAF271C&mode=SIG) for the file signature, it appears to be a 7-zip file format. So AFAICT the file was exported correctly. The extension is `.7z` though, not `.zip`. You can see that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) if you search for the starting bytes `37 7a bc af 27 1c`.

Comment: @TT. Thank you! It really was in .7z format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [here](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=377ABCAF271C&mode=SIG) for the file signature, it appears to be a 7-zip file format. So AFAICT the file was exported correctly. The extension is `.7z` though, not `.zip`.

You can see that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) if you search for the starting bytes `37 7a bc af 27 1c`.